# Get "Encountered unsupported property KeyName" error when start a stack to launch a ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I use `cloudformation` to launch a ec2 instance. Below is the cloudformation template:

```
Parameters:
  KeyName:
    Description: The EC2 Key Pair to allow SSH access to the instance
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName'
Resources:
  Ec2Instance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SpotFleet'
    Properties:
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref InstanceSecurityGroup
        - MyExistingSecurityGroup
      KeyName: !Ref KeyName
      ImageId: ami-07d0cf3af28718ef8
      InstanceType: p2.8xlarge
      AllocationStrategy: lowestPrice
      SpotPrice: 1
  InstanceSecurityGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Enable SSH access via port 22
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

I created a stack in cloudformation and specify the `Key Name` from a drop list of `key pair`. After than the stack rolled back and I see this error message `Encountered unsupported property KeyName`. I wonder what wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check documentation on [`AWS::EC2::SpotFleet`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-spotfleet.html). It only supports `SpotFleetRequestConfigData` as property.

You will probably need to specify something like:

```
  Ec2Instance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SpotFleet'
    Properties:
      SpotFleetRequestConfigData:
        SpotPrice: 1
        AllocationStrategy: lowestPrice
        LaunchSpecifications:
        - InstanceType: p2.8xlarge
          SecurityGroups:
          - !Ref InstanceSecurityGroup
          - MyExistingSecurityGroup
          KeyName: !Ref KeyName
          ImageId: ami-07d0cf3af28718ef8
```

Check the [`AWS::EC2::SpotFleet`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-spotfleet.html) documentation, it has a quite elaborate example.

Comment: Thanks. I think that is. But why doesn't it give a reasonable error message?

Comment: @ZhaoYi Well, in certain sense it does. The error message indicated that `KeyName` is not in the right place. But giving a hint on where it should actually be is probably too much to ask.